# Xamarin : Issue with itemTemplate and focus

Tags: android, xamarin, android-edittext, focus, android-linearlayout

I have a listview with some Blocks.

These Blocks contains 1 to 3 items with itemTemplate which are inside ResourceDictionary.
Blocks and template are correctly displayed, but if I try to add or remove text from fields, it's impossible to edit them.

I set the item template to a label and a entry with entryrenderer for each platform and the issue is solve

I try to set focusable variable and focus state, change descendant focus value without improvements.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please post the relevant code and format it properly.  A link to an external resource is NOT satisfactory according to SO's rules.

Comment: I could, but it's too long and a lot of code. I prefer to share a poc that all users can test and maybe help me according to my example